# Parsing build.gradle using Gradle Tooling API

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

I want to parse the **build.gradle** and list down the dependencies present in it. For that I found below code which is from Gradle tooling API itself. However I get `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gradle.internal.logging.progress.ProgressLoggerFactory`.

I am using gradle 6.6.1 and slf4j jars (*slf4j-api-1.7.32 & sl4j-simple-1.7.32 or slf4j-nop-1.7.32*).

Any pointer on how to resolve the issue or other way to parse the gradle file? Thanks in advance!

My Code:

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Configure the connector and create the connection
    GradleConnector connector = GradleConnector.newConnector();

    if (args.length > 0) {
        connector.useInstallation(new File(args[0]));
        if (args.length > 1) {
            connector.useGradleUserHomeDir(new File(args[1]));
        }
    }

    connector.forProjectDirectory(new File("."));

    ProjectConnection connection = connector.connect();
    try {
        // Load the Eclipse model for the project
        EclipseProject project = connection.getModel(EclipseProject.class);
        System.out.println("Project: " + project.getName());
        System.out.println("Project directory: " + project.getProjectDirectory());
        System.out.println("Source directories:");
        for (EclipseSourceDirectory srcDir : project.getSourceDirectories()) {
            System.out.println(srcDir.getPath());
        }
        System.out.println("Project classpath:");
        for (ExternalDependency externalDependency : project.getClasspath()) {
            System.out.println(externalDependency.getFile().getName());
        }
        System.out.println("Associated gradle project:");
        System.out.println(project.getGradleProject());
    } finally {
        // Clean up
        connection.close();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Gradle has a pretty extensive meta-api and testing framework. Perhaps you can use that?

Comment: @Jorn: Can you point me to the gradle meta-api example/documentation which I can refer? I am not aware of it